# What possible function could the D-0 droid in Star Wars have?

Tags: star-wars

I understand the functions of BB-8, R2D2, C-3PO and other droids introduced in the world, but though I like D-0, I have no idea what he's FOR.

I did a search to research this topic, and all I found was that the creators didn't have a function for him yet, they just created him to be cute and follow BB-8 like a baby duckling.

So my question is: What could D-0 be for? What function could he possibly actually be built for?

A bad man had him for a bit--but why did he keep this droid at all?

Comment: I thought the D-0 droids were just portable security cameras but the one following BB-8 around actually served a purpose to the plot of *The Rise of Skywalker*.

Comment: The let's try to explain it answer is "probably translation or as an alert system", the practical answer "Marketing gimmick to sell toys"

Comment: @A.bakker At JJ's pitiful attempt to create a "cute" character for the sole purpose of pushing toy sales, Baby Yoda laughs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The droid D-O seems to serve multiple purposes throughout its lifetime. It was, initially, an amusement for whoever created it. Described as a "*hobby droid*" by the Rise of Skywalker Visual Dictionary, it would appear that its original builder was merely playing with droid tech and cobbled it together to while away time.

> *"Homemade hobby droids are more common in the Mid Rim and Outer Rim,
> where distribution lines of major droid corporations don't always
> reach."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

Later on, after the droid was taken as booty by Ochi (after killing its original owner), he adapted it to contain a large data storage module containing, amongst other things, the traveling coordinates to Exegol, presumably as a backup to his Navicomp.

> *Ochi claimed D-O after slaying the droid's master. Despite such dark
> origins, D-O doesn't have an ill-intentioned subroutine in his
> personality matrix. **He was a simple amusement for Ochi at first, then
> a data storage module,** and ultimately neglected and discarded. He
> remained inactive for more than a decade aboard Ochi's ship.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

The wealth of after-market signalling and sensor gear on the front of the droid would strongly imply that Ochi (an archaeologist) used the droid to store information about his studies and transmit them to a secondary archive, possibly on his ship.

Comment: I found the D-0 droid oddly reminiscent of the [butter robot](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Butter_Robot) from Rick and Morty's S01E09 although I have no evidence that it is a homage or otherwise.